# Bootstrap 4.1 carousel not showing in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4

I have a page with the Bootstrap 4.1 carousel component on it.
It works perfectly in Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Edge, but in IE 11 is just shows a blank screen area.
This is the link to the page: [Web page with Carousel](http://www.claudiaspaziani.com)

How do you get around this issue?
I have not been able to find any answer searching on Google or consulting the Bootstrap home page.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: this [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22882) says that this bug still exists.

Comment: Thanks MajiD., I would expect that this kind of bug would have been solved by official release 4.1, but apparently it's not...

Comment: I also have the problem with Bootstrap 4.1.3. 
The code from this example will not display images in IE11:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/carousel/